# Error when trying to load data form mysql server to jqgrid

Tags: jquery, jqgrid, jqgrid-php

I was following along with this tutorial ([http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:first_grid](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki%3afirst_grid)) but there seems to be an issue. The error I keep getting is,

> XMLHttpRequest cannot load file:///Applications/MAMP/htdocs/QA%20User%20Manager/views/example.php?_search=false&nd=1399384293460&rows=10&page=1&sidx=invid&sord=desc. Received an invalid response. Origin 'null' is therefore not allowed access.

I'm not sure if this has to do with connecting to the server DB, which is served via localhost. Or this could be something else.

Comment: Looks like some of the comments here will help you out - http://www.larryullman.com/forums/index.php?/topic/2189-chapter-11-cant-get-ajax-to-work-on-ie-or-chrome/ Are you running the file you're requesting from your MAMP server?

Comment: Yes, I'm trying to request the data from a localhost database running on of MAMP.